# Can android studio java app become the updated version of xamarin android app?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing xamarin android app and I know after some months I am going to change the technology from .net to java. Suppose my app version is 1.1. Can java app become 1.2 as the updated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you use the same package name and keystore to release version 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just export it with same **keystore** and the same **package name** and **increment the version**.